# How to return a cell value from Pandas instead of a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling a lot using pandas LOC to get one cell value. It always return a series.

For example:

```
    filter=(data['Well']==well)&(data['Date']==thisdate)
    data_thiswell_thisdate=data.loc[filter,'Steam']   # after filter, it is a series
    print(data_thiswell_thisdate)
```

When printing, the result is below with index and value:

```
4302    0.0000
```

In order to get value, I have to use values[0]. Why? Is it LOC to get cell value?

```
data_thiswell_thisdate=data.loc[filter,'Steam'].values[0]
```

Could you please help me understand how to use LOC in pandas? Thanks.

Comment: `data_thiswell_thisdate = data.loc[filter,'Steam'].iloc[0]`

Comment: Thanks, why has to use iloc[0]? That is where I don't uderstand it. why not directly use LOC[]. The pandas LOC documentation say, LOC is to get cell value by giving row and column. Is it right?

Comment: loc access a group always -> "Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array." whereas iloc access based on index ->  "Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position."

Comment: Thanks anky. I still don't get it. sorry. If filtered group is only one line, why LOC cannot give a cell value. ok, if just using ILOC w/o using LOC, how do you write the line? Thanks

Comment: _If filtered group is only one line, why LOC cannot give a cell value._ It's probably just a design choice. _ok, if just using ILOC w/o using LOC, how do you write the line?_ Check out [the indexing docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: Here is pandas website, where using loc to access a cell value: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: @roudan Is that in response to my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in order to get value, I have to do using values[0]. why? Is it LOC to get cell value?

You obtained a *series*, although only *1-element* series.
It is something like a *1-element list* `[0.0000]` — to obtain its (only one) element, you must nevertheless use its index (`[0]`).

No, it is not the `.loc[]` method, it is common indexing starting with index `0`.

`.loc[]` method uses a row *label* (i.e. an index value):

```
data_thiswell_thisdate.loc[4302]
```

If you want to use `.loc[]` to obtain an element from a *dataframe* (as opposed to a series), you provide a row label *and* a column label (in this order) — for example in your case you may directly access your value in the form

```
data.loc[4302, 'Steam']
```

(of course, if you knew the index value (`4302`) in advance).

Comment: Thanks MarianD. I appreciate it. Let me try to understant it. so if I use boolean array for row label, the returned result will be always either dataframe or series.  If I want to get cell values, I have to use its index value. Is it right? Thanks

Comment: @roudan, you're totally right (for `.loc[]`). Please consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer if it was useful for you.